# Can you send arguments to an already running click once application from a webpage?

Tags: c#, javascript, clickonce

I have a click once application that that is installed from a page, is it possible to send new arguments to it if its already open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, except startup arguments you won't be able to communicate with it. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76e4d2xw.aspx) link, look at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not. You need an implementation of inter-process communication (Remoting, WCF, ...)